# Required. Should have privileged access, such as root or administrator in manageiq

Tags: monitoring, hawkular

I try to monitor Hawkular with manageiq on Centos 7. These are my monitoring implementation process which are run on root privilege.

First cassandra nosql db is executed.

```
# systemctl start cassandra
```

And next I execute the hawkular server like below as root

```
# unzip hawkular-services-dist-0.23.0.Final.zip
# ./add-user.sh -a -u username -p password -g read-write,read-only
# ./standalone.sh -Dhawkular.rest.user=username -Dhawkular.rest.password=password -Dhawkular.agent.enabled=true
```

And then, I run Docker and related manageiq docker-image.

```
# systemctl start docker
# docker pull manageiq/manageiq:euwe-1
# docker run --privileged -d -p 8443:443 manageiq/manageiq:euwe-1
```

I run manageiq on Firefox with the following address and it works successfully with user admin and password smartvm.

```
https://localhost:8443
```

And I try to add Hawkular middleware on manageiq web UI with the menu "Add New Middleware Provider" However error message is shown,

```
"Required. Should have privileged access, such as root or administrator."
```

I cannot understand this error message. Hawkular server and manageiq are run on root privilege. How can I add Hawkular service into manageiq monitoring service?

Comment: Is there anything related to this in the MangeIQ logs? Are you able to add a different kind of provider?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It seems I have some problems with the docker certificate files of .docker folder. The web browser clients have no previlige to access mqanageiq docker container without .docker folder. But I have no idea where to generate docker certificates files on centos 7. Any idea?

Comment: Is it possible that this is a simple file permission issue? E.g. when you 1st run docker as root and then later as non-root user, which can't access that .docker dir?

Comment: After running docker manageiq container, I execute " docker exec -ti <Container_NAME> bash -l" to access docker container and "# machinectl" on manageiq container inside. But no machine returns. ManageIQ seems not to be executed on the container. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. My OS is windows 10 pro, but my hyper-v service was deactivated. I activated hyper-v and it worked well. Thanks any way

Comment: Glad it works. So you run Hawkular-services + C* also on HyperV on Win10?

Comment: Actually, not perfectly. Pls, check this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41933290/manageiq-docker-container-cannot-not-be-connected-with-web-browser  Best regards.